# NgRx State Reset to Null After Successful Authentication Action and Component Refresh

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-standalone-components

After a successful authentication action, the NgRx state is correctly updated with the authenticated user. However, upon refreshing the component or navigating, the data in the state appears to be reset to null.

user.action :

```
export const setUser = createAction('[User] Set User', props<{ user: User }>());
```

index.ts:

```
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<AppState>[] = isDevMode() ? [] : [];
```

user.reducer:

```
export interface UserState {
    user: User | null;
  }

  export const initialState: UserState = {
    user: null,
  };

  export const userReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(UserActions.setUser, (state, { user }) => ({ ...state, user }))
  );
```

user.selector:

```
export const selectUserState = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('user');

export const selectUser = createSelector(
  selectUserState,
  (state) => state.user
);
```

app.state

```
import { UserState } from './reducers/user.reducer';

export interface AppState {
  user: UserState;
}
```

app.config:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding()),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    importProvidersFrom([
      HttpClientModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot(provideTranslation()),
    ]),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideStore(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    provideStoreDevtools({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !isDevMode() }),
  ],
};
```

I expected that, after a successful authentication, the NgRx state would retain the user data across component refresh or navigation. However, despite the correct dispatch of the setUser action, the data in the state appears to reset to null upon component refresh or navigation.

Comment: " However, upon refreshing the component or navigating, the data in the state appears to be reset to null." You are saying that if you refresh the app (F5 the page) the data doesn't persist? If I got it right, then that's expected, ngrx or any state management tool doesn't persist the data, in that case you would need to use local storage or similar...

Comment: @Andres2142 Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, the issue occurs not when refreshing the entire page (F5), but rather when navigating between components within the application without performing a full page refresh. In this context, I expected the NgRx state to persist across component changes, and it's this behavior that seems unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

NgRx only keeps state in memory (and thus loses its state on a refresh). If you want to persist state across reloads, you can use the local/session storage, e.g. with https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage

> the issue occurs not when refreshing the entire page (F5), but rather when navigating between components within the application without performing a full page refresh.

This shouldn't happen. But it's hard to say what's wrong without the whole picture/an example.

It seems like something is resetting the state, or the selector isn't wired up currectly.

I recommend to use the NgRx DevTools to see what's going on, and what's affecting the state.

Another thing that I can think of is that there's a full page reload while navigating, which is not intended.